# Javascript redirect based on referrer client login

Tags: javascript, redirect, authentication, passwords, client

having a little issue figuring this out

i have a photography website with a very unsecure login section for clients to access a gallery of their photos. (aware its unsecure but if we could solve this problem then its fine)

normal flow should look like this:
enter index.html > clients.html > client types in code for ex. 9999 > client taken to clients/9999.html

the reason for creating these galleries was to drive more traffic to my websites landing page (index.html). 
i cover an event, publish photos in gallery, and give out a code. goal is to have my clients give out my website and code to all guests that attended the event, thus before they access the clients/9999.html gallery page, they are forced to get a glimpse of index.html which has my main portfolio.

however, what i have realized has been happening is my clients are not sharing my website and code, but rather a direct link with their guests. so all viewers are visiting 9999.html from a direct link that points to it, and completely omit viewing index.html. 90% of traffic falls off after they view 9999.html which is no good.

i am trying to fix this with a redirect based on referral link, however i am having trouble and the following code seems to be redirecting all traffic, even if i "login" properly by going through index.html > clients.html > enter code

```
<!--Redirect if not from Client Page-->
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer !== "../clients.html") {
    document.location.href = "../index.html";
}
</script>
<!--End Redirect-->
```

any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You are testing the referrer wrong. It will never be ../xxxxxx

Also it is window.location, not document.location

Instead set a cookie on the index page so they at least have seen it once.

If you insist on testing the referrer:

```
var ref = document.referrer;
var host = ref.indexOf(location.hostname) !=-1; // www.yoursite.com
var page = ref.indexOf('clients.html') !=-1; // page name
if (!host || !page) location.replace("../index.html");
```

which can all be circumvented if we turn JS off

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. rather than assuming clients.html has to be the referrer, i simply changed it to redirect if there is a null referrer

so:

```
<!--Redirect if not from Client Page-->
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer == '') {
    document.location.href = "../index.html";
}
</script>
<!--End Redirect-->
```

Comment: That means anyone not passing referrer (it can be turned off for security reasons) will be redirected and anyone passing a referrer from anywhere will not